# SQL for duplicate from reference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to write a sql query by avoiding records getting duplicated from source.I have two tables master(T1) and reference(T2).

Master Table(T1)

```
C_NO    SURNAME ID
1234    Jeeju   1111
4567    Balu    1111
```

Reference Table(T2)

```
ID      C_NO
1111    1234
1111    4567
1111    54378
```

I am doing a join based on **ID** column.My master table(T1) is **source** and **reference** table(T2) is the one which I am doing the left outer join.Currently its going for a Cartesian.I want an output as given below.The two records from source should come as it is and only the record from T2 should get duplicated.

```
C_NO    SURNAME ID
1234    Jeeju   1111
4567    Balu    1111
54378   Jeeju   1111
54378   Balu    1111
```

Comment: What sql have you written so far to try and join the tables?

Comment: If you do a left join it *won't* be a Cartesian join; but you will get duplicate rows if your join criteria (`t1.id = t2.id`) is not based on a unique identifier in one of the tables. Since `ID` is not unique in either of your tables, you will get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you actually want to concatenate all the rows from your source table (T1) and then append any new records in the reference table, by joining on both `id` and `c_no`, e.g.:

```
create table t1 (c_no number, surname varchar2(100), id number);
create table t2 (id number, c_no number);
insert into t1 values (1234,'Jeeju',1111);
insert into t1 values (4567,'Balu',1111);
insert into t2 values (1111,1234);
insert into t2 values (1111,4567);
insert into t2 values (1111,54378);

select c_no, surname, id
from t1
union all
select t2.c_no, t1.surname, t2.id
from t2 join t1 on t1.id = t2.id
where not exists (
  select null
  from t1 x
  where x.id = t2.id
  and x.c_no = t2.c_no
);

C_NO    SURNAME ID
======= ======= ====
1234    Jeeju   1111
4567    Balu    1111
54378   Jeeju   1111
54378   Balu    1111
```

Answer (score 0):

add a simple distinct keyword and it should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.C_NO,t1.SURNAME,t2.id
FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
```

BTW i think the output data you showed does not match your inputs. There is not entry for id '54378'

Comment: `54378` comes from the reference table (T2).

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
declare @tab table (C_NO int,   SURNAME varchar(20),ID int)
insert into @tab values(
1234    ,'Jeeju',   1111),(
4567    ,'Balu',    1111)


declare @tab1 table(ID int,      C_NO int)
insert into @tab1 values (
1111    ,1234),(
1111    ,4567),(
1111    ,54378)


select t2.C_NO,t1.SURNAME,t2.ID
from @tab t1
inner join @tab1 t2 on t1.C_NO <> t2.C_NO
```

output

```
C_NO    SURNAME ID
1234    Balu    1111
4567    Jeeju   1111
54378   Jeeju   1111
54378   Balu    1111
```

Comment: Interesting interpretation of the requirements; I'm not sure this is what was meant although the results happen to agree with the expected results. Note this is not valid Oracle syntax.

Comment: Yes @JeffreyKemp you are right i am working on it.. thanks for ur feedback

Comment: Thanks All. HI Jeff and Ajay, thanks for understanding my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simple left join below should works as intended:

```
Select distinct T1.SURNAME, T1.ID, T1.C_NO 
FROM T1
  LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
```